# Add a colon after two characters without using String.replace

Tags: javascript, string, format

I am currently using replace to insert a colon after the **second character** of a **four-character** string (1000). I think it is an elegant solution. But I wonder if there are any other elegant solutions for this? Thanks for your ideas!

**Working code**

```js
const myStr = "1000";
const string = myStr.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1:$2');
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Will the pattern be always the same like XX:XX?

Comment: @LarsFlieger Allways the same (XX:XX).

Answer (score 3):

You could stil take a regular expression which works for any time length, like four or six digits with colon for each group of two.

```js
const 
    format = s => s.replace(/.(?=(..)+$)/g, '$&:');
    
console.log(format('1000'));
console.log(format('100000'));
```

Comment: that is good solution. Thank you. Current I need only for strings with 4 digits. But good to know that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. Use string functions to manipulate strings:

```js
const s1 = "1000";
const s2 = s1.slice(0, 2) + ":" + s1.slice(2);
console.log(s2);
```

Comment: You could use template literals as well: `${x.slice(0, 2)}:${x.slice(2)}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240039/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-lars-flieger).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the best way to do that, i'm just wondering how many alternatives there are

```js
[...'1000'].map((c, i) => i !== 0 && i % 2 === 0 ? `:${c}` : c).join('') //10:00
[...'100000'].map((c, i) => i !== 0 && i % 2 === 0 ? `:${c}` : c).join('') //10:00:00
[...'10000000'].map((c, i) => i !== 0 && i % 2 === 0 ? `:${c}` : c).join('') //10:00:00:00
```

Comment: In any case, this is also an interesting possibility that works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const x = "1000"
const result = `${x.slice(0, 2)}:${x.slice(2)}`
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a substring, somthing like this

```js
var mystring = '1000';

var method1 = mystring.substring(0, 2) + ':' + mystring.substr(2);

console.log(method1);
```

and u can make your own function

```js
String.prototype.insert = function(index, string) {
  if (index > 0){
    return this.substring(0, index) + string + this.substr(index);
   }
  return string + this;
};

var mystring='1000';

var method2=mystring.insert(2,':');

console.log(method2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answear.

Comment: Don't use `substr`, it is being retired